# How to pass cakephp formhelper input values to ajax via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am still new to cakephp, and my attempt is to retrieve the FormHelper's value and pass it via $.ajax() call in jquery. However, by cakephp convention, the name of each field generated by FormHelper will be in the format of `data[Model][field]`. Now, I want to submit $_POST data in form of cakephp array format. However, I couldn't find a way to do so, because I couldn't find a way to turn name and value attribute into a passable array format.

My attempt was to turn everything into string and try to create a json array. However, I failed to do so, and this method doesn't seem convincing to me too.

```
function submitEdit(sendurl, formid){
  var dataset = [];
  $('form#'+ formid + ' > input,select').each(function(){
    dataset.push($(this).attr('name') + ':' + $(this).val());
  });

  alert(dataset);
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: '{' + dataset + ']',
        url: sendurl,
        success: function(content){
          $('.setting-preview.username').append('<pre>' + content + '</pre>');
        }
  });
}
```

Therefore, how do I pass this as `data[Model][field]` array to the `sendurl` controller?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Model: {
                 foo: $('#ModelFoo').val(),
                 bar: $('#ModelBar').val()
            }
        },
        url: sendurl,
        success: function(content){
          $('.setting-preview.username').append('<pre>' + content + '</pre>');
        }
  });
```